# Auto-comments for Music Fans

Tags: discussion, comments

[Auto-comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) for Music Fans are now available. The purpose of this is to help users and avoid re-typing always the same comments for similar cases.

### How to install the script

1. Userscripts add functionality to the site by running scripts in your browser. All major browsers support userscripts by installing a userscript manager extension, for example [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).
2. [Install](https://raw.github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js) the script. Now, when you click on "comment", you should see "auto":

[image: auto1]

3. Update the comment list by clicking on "remote"

[image: auto2]

Then in the dialog, enter the adress

`https://comments.socvr.org/jsonp-data/musicfans.stackexchange.com`

click "get now" then "save".

### I don't want to install the script

You can still have access to the comments [here](https://comments.socvr.org/jsonp-data/musicfans.stackexchange.com).

---

If you want to help increasing the comment list, you can participate in this [github](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments) project.